# Moving Resources, what happens to policies? Can you move read locked resources?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

Moving resources in Azure seems to be a hectic process.

I have two resource groups RG1 and RG2.

RG1 has a virtual machine VM1 (delete locked).
RG2 has a virtual machine VM2 (read-only locked).

I thought I can move VM1 to RG2 but it didn't pull through! I got an error and further more I lost both my VM2 while attempting that.

Same thing happened to VM2.

I have three questions:

1. Can you move a read-only or delete resources to another resource group?
2. If a resource group is locked (delete or read-only), can you move resources from it? or to it?
3. Let's say I assigned a policy to RG1 and another policy to RG2. If I moved a resource from RG1 to RG2, will it now work under a new policy in the resource group or will it retain its policy under the old resource group after the move is done?

If any one can can at least show me an Azure article that addresses my questions I will much thankful.